# Active Directory DNS issue? Event ID 13 Access Denied,

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Okay this is kind of a rehash of a prior post. (https://serverfault.com/questions/479617/clustered-storage-error-there-are-currently-no-logon-servers-available-to-servi) due to my belief that it is unrelated to the cluster based on new information.

So you don't have to read it, the issue I'm having is that after a period of time I start getting the error "There are currently no login servers available to services the login request" when accessing a cluster volume. A reboot of the server resolves the issue - temporarily, but then it comes back after an hour or so. Only on inactive volumes though. Note: With a fresh boot of all the member servers I can validate the cluster completely and browse all volumes from all servers.

I believe this to be either an Active Directory or DNS issue. But, I'm not sure where to start to resolve the issue. I'm pretty green on AD.

Our network is pretty simple. We have an HQ office with a Win2k3 PDC/DNS/DHCP and workstations, and a routing & remote access/gateway server with a static VPN to the NOC. At the NOC we have a DC/DNS/RRAS server that the cluster and servers talk to.

On the NOC DC I'm seeing the following errors in the event viewer:

**Event ID 13** Automatic certificate enrollment for local system failed to enroll for one Domain Controller certificate (0x80070005).  Access is denied.

**Event ID 10016** The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{BA126AD1-2166-11D1-B1D0-00805FC1270E}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SID (S-1-5-20).  This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

**Event ID 5805** The session setup from the computer SERVERNAME failed to authenticate. The following error occurred: 
Access is denied.

I believe this may be the root cause, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Just a note, the cluster is all Win2k8 R2. Just the DC and PDC are Win2k3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Got it solved. It was definitely an AD/DNS issue. There were some bad DNS records that were fouling up AD replication and in turn causing authentication issues.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work